# How to use value from one table and return some calculations based on different table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables

**trade_table** as

| id | start_date | transacted_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-02-14 | 2022-02-17 |
| A1 | 2022-02-17 | 2022-02-25 |
| A5 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-19 |
| A6 | 2022-02-21 | NULL |

and
**trading_days** as

| trade_date |
| --- |
| 2022-02-14 |
| 2022-02-15 |
| 2022-02-16 |
| 2022-02-17 |
| 2022-02-19 |
| 2022-02-21 |
| 2022-02-23 |
| 2022-02-25 |

How to get actual date difference from trade_date table based on values from transacted_date and start_date from trade_table.

Expected Output table

| id | start_date | transacted_date | transact_in_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-02-14 | 2022-02-17 | 3 |
| A1 | 2022-02-17 | 2022-02-25 | 4 |
| A2 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-19 | 3 |
| A6 | 2022-02-21 | NULL | null |

Answer (score 1):

In oracle can you try so:

```
select a.*,
       (
        select decode(count(*)-1,-1,null,count(*)-1)
          from trading_days 
         where nvl(trade_date, '0001-01-01') 
               between a.start_date and a.transacted_date
       ) as transact_in_days
   from trade_table a;
                      
ID START_DATE TRANSACTED TRANSACT_IN_DAYS                        
-- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
A1 2022-02-14 2022-02-17 3                                       
A1 2022-02-17 2022-02-25 4                                       
A5 2022-02-15 2022-02-19 3                                       
A6 2022-02-21 null       null
```

Comment: same error , Correlated column is not allowed in predicate –

Comment: You can try to substitute "a.*," with "a.id, a.start_date, a.transacted_date,"

Answer (score 1):

> select id,start_date,transacted_date, CASE WHEN transacted_date IS
> NULL THEN NULL ELSE  (select count(1)-1 from trading_days where
> trade_date between start_date and transacted_date) END as
> transact_in_days from trade_table

[image]

Comment: Correlated column is not allowed in predicate